# Lining up issue

Tags: html, css

So I'm writing some HML & CSS for drop-down lists and I got it to work, but I get a problem when adding more than 2 elements in the div, the elements after the second one are being tabbed down. I can't figure out what's the problem, any suggestions?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DID XHTML 1.0 Transitional// EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtmli/DTD.xhtmli-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dropDown.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" contents="text/html; charst=utf-8" />
<title> My Website </title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="navMenu">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>     
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Top 10 Defenders </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 1 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 2 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 3 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 4 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 5 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 6 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 7 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 8 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 9 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 10 </li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Top 10 Midfielders </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 1 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 2 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 3 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 4 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 5 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 6 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 7 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 8 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 9 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 10 </li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Top 10 Forwards </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 1 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 2 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 3 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 4 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 5 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 6 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 7 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 8 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 9 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 10 </li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Best Formations </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 1 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 2 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 3 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 4 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 5 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 6 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 7 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 8 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 9 </li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 10 </li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

#navMenu{

    margin:0;
    width:75%;
    padding:0;

}

#navMenu ul{

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;


}

#navMenu li{

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;

}

#navMenu ul li a{

    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;

}

#navMenu ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    top:30px;
}

#navMenu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

So my page looks like this at the moment:

[image]

Comment: In your `#navMenu ul ul` you have `top:30px;`.  This will lower everything down as shown in your picture (in combination with the `position:absolute;`).

Comment: Try closing your links properly `</a>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 30px height in the navMenu ul li a .. meaning it will be pushed down.

Also I must point out that you re not using the your list items correctly. You close after each item in your upper list your unordened list, which is not neccesairy. I made a fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/kad97ro1/

```
#navMenu ul li a{   
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    color:#000;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `height:30px;` of your `#navMenu ul li a`, remove it and everything will be fine:

```
#navMenu ul li a{

text-align:center;
font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
text-decoration:none;
width:150px;
display:block;
color:#000;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the anchor elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DID XHTML 1.0 Transitional// EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtmli/DTD.xhtmli-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dropDown.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" contents="text/html; charst=utf-8" />
<title> My Website </title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="navMenu">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>     
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Top 10 Defenders </a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#"> Title 1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 2 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 3 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 4 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 5 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 6 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 7 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 8 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 9 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 10 </a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Top 10 Midfielders </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 2 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 3 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 4 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 5 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 6 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 7 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 8 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 9 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 10 </a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Top 10 Forwards </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 2 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 3 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 4 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 5 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 6 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 7 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 8 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 9 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 10 </a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Best Formations </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 2 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 3 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 4 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 5 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 6 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 7 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 8 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 9 </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Title 10 </a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although this is not the current problem of OP, this is indeed an issue he should adres